# Typescript definition(xxx.d.ts)

Tags: typescript

I want to use the keyword as the function name in the declaration file(.d.ts), but there seems to be an error, how to deal with this problem?

The error just like this ↓:
[image]

Comment: Please don’t post errors or code as images. And the image doesn’t even include the error text, which must exist somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `try` is not a valid name for a function. If you try to run the code `function try() {}` in a browser console you will get an error. Since this is the case, typescript will not let you use it as a name for a function in a declaration.